# How to chain scope queries with OR instead of AND?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails3, ActiveRecord

Just wondering how can I chain the scopes with OR statements rather than AND.

e.g.

```
Person.where(:name => "John").where(:lastname => "Smith")
```

That normally returns:

```
name = 'John' AND lastname = 'Smith'
```

but I'd like:

```
`name = 'John' OR lastname = 'Smith'
```

Answer (score 124):

You would do

```
Person.where('name=? OR lastname=?', 'John', 'Smith')
```

Right now, there isn't any other OR support by the new AR3 syntax (that is without using some 3rd party gem).

Answer (score 88):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052), Rails 5 now supports the following syntax for chaining queries:

```
Post.where(id: 1).or(Post.where(id: 2))
```

There's also a backport of the functionality into Rails 4.2 via [this gem.](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me (running Rails 6.1)

Answer (score 63):

Just posting the Array syntax for **same** column OR queries to help peeps out.

```
Person.where(name: ["John", "Steve"])
```

Answer (score 53):

Use [ARel](http://github.com/rails/arel)

```
t = Person.arel_table

results = Person.where(
  t[:name].eq("John").
  or(t[:lastname].eq("Smith"))
)
```

Comment: It comes bundled with the Active Record gem now.

Answer (score 40):

**Update for Rails4**

requires no 3rd party gems

```
a = Person.where(name: "John") # or any scope 
b = Person.where(lastname: "Smith") # or any scope 
Person.where([a, b].map{|s| s.arel.constraints.reduce(:and) }.reduce(:or))\
  .tap {|sc| sc.bind_values = [a, b].map(&:bind_values) }
```

**Old answer**

requires no 3rd party gems

```
Person.where(
    Person.where(:name => "John").where(:lastname => "Smith")
      .where_values.reduce(:or)
)
```

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone is looking for an updated answer to this one, it looks like there is an existing pull request to get this into Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9052.

Thanks to @j-mcnally's monkey patch for ActiveRecord (https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/250eaaceef234dd8971b) you can do the following:

```
Person.where(name: 'John').or.where(last_name: 'Smith').all
```

Even more valuable is the ability to chain scopes with `OR`:

```
scope :first_or_last_name, ->(name) { where(name: name.split(' ').first).or.where(last_name: name.split(' ').last) }
scope :parent_last_name, ->(name) { includes(:parents).where(last_name: name) }
```

Then you can find all Persons with first or last name or whose parent with last name

```
Person.first_or_last_name('John Smith').or.parent_last_name('Smith')
```

Not the best example for the use of this, but just trying to fit it with the question.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) gem to not mix up your code with SQL stuff:

```
Person.where((:name => "John") | (:lastname => "Smith"))
```

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking to provide a scope (instead of explicitly working on the whole dataset) here's what you should do with Rails 5:

```
scope :john_or_smith, -> { where(name: "John").or(where(lastname: "Smith")) }
```

Or:

```
def self.john_or_smith
  where(name: "John").or(where(lastname: "Smith"))
end
```

Answer (score 11):

For me (Rails 4.2.5) it only works like this:

```
{ where("name = ? or name = ?", a, b) }
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm working in Rails 6 now and it seems like this is now possible. Using the queries from the OP:

```
# in the Person model:
scope :john, -> { where(name: "John") }
scope :smith, -> { where(lastname: "Smith") }
scope :john_or_smith, -> { john.or(self.smith) }
```

Answer (score 9):

This would be a good candidate for MetaWhere if you're using Rails 3.0+, but it doesn't work on Rails 3.1. You might want to try out [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) instead. It's made by the same author. Here's how'd you'd perform an OR based chain:

```
Person.where{(name == "John") | (lastname == "Smith")}
```

You can mix and match AND/OR, among many other [awesome things](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).

Answer (score 8):

An updated version of Rails/ActiveRecord may support this syntax natively. It would look similar to:

```
Foo.where(foo: 'bar').or.where(bar: 'bar')
```

As noted in this pull request https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9052

For now, simply sticking with the following works great:

```
Foo.where('foo= ? OR bar= ?', 'bar', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 6):

Rails 4 + Scope + Arel

```
class Creature < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :is_good_pet, -> {
        where(
            arel_table[:is_cat].eq(true)
            .or(arel_table[:is_dog].eq(true))
            .or(arel_table[:eats_children].eq(false))
        )
    }
end
```

I tried chaining named scopes with .or and no luck, but this worked for finding anything with those booleans set. Generates SQL like

```
SELECT 'CREATURES'.* FROM 'CREATURES' WHERE ((('CREATURES'.'is_cat' = 1 OR 'CREATURES'.'is_dog' = 1) OR 'CREATURES'.'eats_children' = 0))
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a very convenient way and it works fine in Rails 5:

```
Transaction
  .where(transaction_type: ["Create", "Correspond"])
  .or(
    Transaction.where(
      transaction_type: "Status",
      field: "Status",
      newvalue: ["resolved", "deleted"]
    )
  )
  .or(
    Transaction.where(transaction_type: "Set", field: "Queue")
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4

```
scope :combined_scope, -> { where("name = ? or name = ?", 'a', 'b') }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't write out the where clause manually to include the "or" statement (ie, you want to combine two scopes), you can use union:

```
Model.find_by_sql("#{Model.scope1.to_sql} UNION #{Model.scope2.to_sql}")
```

(source: [ActiveRecord Query Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union))

This is will return all records matching either query. However, this returns an array, not an arel. If you really want to return an arel, you checkout this gist: https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/250eaaceef234dd8971b.

This will do the job, as long as you don't mind monkey patching rails.

Answer (score 2):

*Also see these related questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445203/combining-multiple-named-scopes-with-or), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482940/combine-two-named-scopes-with-or-instead-of-and) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381619/using-or-with-queries-in-a-scope)*

For rails 4, based on [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/dgv7ag/or-queries-with-arrays-as-arguments-in-rails-4) and [this original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865634/1876622)

```
Person
  .unscoped # See the caution note below. Maybe you want default scope here, in which case just remove this line.
  .where( # Begin a where clause
    where(:name => "John").where(:lastname => "Smith")  # join the scopes to be OR'd
    .where_values  # get an array of arel where clause conditions based on the chain thus far
    .inject(:or)  # inject the OR operator into the arels 
    # ^^ Inject may not work in Rails3. But this should work instead:
    .joins(" OR ")
    # ^^ Remember to only use .inject or .joins, not both
  )  # Resurface the arels inside the overarching query
```

**Note** the article's caution at the end:

> Rails 4.1+
>
> Rails 4.1 treats default_scope just as a regular scope. The default
>   scope (if you have any) is included in the where_values result and
>   inject(:or) will add or statement between the default scope and your
>   wheres. That's bad.
>
> To solve that, you just need to unscope the query.

Answer (score 0):

the `squeel` gem provides an incredibly easy way to accomplish this (prior to this I used something like @coloradoblue's method):

```
names = ["Kroger", "Walmart", "Target", "Aldi"]
matching_stores = Grocery.where{name.like_any(names)}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to the original question, can you join scopes with 'or' instead of 'and' seems to be "no you can't". But you can hand code a completely different scope or query that does the job, or use a different framework from ActiveRecord e.g. MetaWhere or Squeel. Not useful in my case

I'm 'or'ing a scope generated by pg_search, which does a bit more than select, it includes order by ASC, which makes a mess of a clean union. I want to 'or' it with a handcrafted scope that does stuff I can't do in pg_search. So I've had to do it like this.

```
Product.find_by_sql("(#{Product.code_starts_with('Tom').to_sql}) union (#{Product.name_starts_with('Tom').to_sql})")
```

I.e. turn the scopes into sql, put brackets around each one, union them together and then find_by_sql using the sql generated. It's a bit rubbish, but it does work.

No, don't tell me I can use "against: [:name,:code]" in pg_search, I'd like to do it like that, but the 'name' field is an hstore, which pg_search can't handle yet. So the scope by name has to be hand crafted and then unioned with the pg_search scope.

Answer (score -3):

```
names = ["tim", "tom", "bob", "alex"]
sql_string = names.map { |t| "name = '#{t}'" }.join(" OR ")
@people = People.where(sql_string)
```

Comment: This allows SQL injection via the `#{t}` construct.