# Is it possible to do an "OR" on two ActiveRecord scopes using MetaWhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, meta-where

Is it possible to do an "OR" on two scopes?

For example, consider a simple example where I have a class User with 2 scopes - professors and lecturers

Then, can I re-use the 2 scopes to get users who may be either professors or lecturers?
Some thing like User.professors.or.lecturers

Answer (score 0):

Metawhere allows you write conditions inside scopes as a Ruby statements it doesn't have any influence on scopes. Since (and unfortunately) in Rails scopes are joined (AFAIK) using only `AND` you can't achieve what you want. Possible solution of the problem is new scope `proffesors_or_lecturers` also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and)