# Rails - How to force associations to use alias table name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
p = Patient.find(30)

p.patient_problems
```

The above code generates the following query

```
SELECT `patient_problem`.* FROM `patient_problem` WHERE `patient_problem`.`patient_id` = 30 AND (`patient_problem`.`record_status_id` = 1)
```

But is there any way to assign/use alias table_name like

```
p.patient_problems(:alias=>'p1') # just for Ex.. This code will not work
p.patient_problems(:alias=>'p2') # just for Ex.. This code will not work
```

So it will generate the following queries

```
SELECT `p1`.* FROM `patient_problem` AS `p1` WHERE `p1`.`patient_id` = 30 AND (`p1`.`record_status_id` = 1)

SELECT `p2`.* FROM `patient_problem` AS `p2` WHERE `p2`.`patient_id` = 30 AND (`p2`.`record_status_id` = 1)
```

---

**Additional Info**

My problem is when I try to use joins

p.patient_problems(:all,:joins=>joins)

I get this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Not unique table/alias: 'patient_problem': SELECT `patient_problem`.* FROM `patient_problem` LEFT OUTER JOIN party on party.id = patient_problem.patient_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN party_identifier on party.id = party_identifier.party_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN blood_type on blood_type.id = party.blood_type_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN education_level on education_level.id = party.education_level_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN religion on religion.id = party.religion_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN living_arrangement on living_arrangement.id = party.living_arrangement_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN patient_problem patient_problem on patient_problem.patient_id = party.id and patient_problem.record_status_id = 1 
          left join (select user_type,username,user_id,auditable_id from (select MAX(id) id from audits where audits.auditable_type = 'PatientProblem' and user_type is not null group by auditable_id ) t inner join audits v on v.id=t.id ) entered_by1 on entered_by1.auditable_id = patient_problem.id
          left outer join user user1 on entered_by1.user_id = user1.id
          left outer join party as party_user1 on party_user1.id = user1.person_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN patient_patient_search patient_patient_search1  on patient_patient_search1.patient_id = party.id
         left join search search1 on patient_patient_search1.patient_search_id = search1.id
         and patient_patient_search1.patient_search_id = '75' WHERE `patient_problem`.`patient_id` = 45 AND (`patient_problem`.`record_status_id` = 1) AND (  (patient_problem.occurrence_date > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and patient_problem.occurrence_date < '2013-06-30 23:59:59' and   patient_problem.patient_problem_status_id in (5) and  patient_problem.code is not null and  patient_problem.code in ('10725009') )  and   (  patient_patient_search1.patient_search_id in (75.0) )  ))
```

Ofcourse I could do some string manipulation on the generated joins query and set alias to patient_problem. But I thought setting alias for associations would be more cleaner since the joins query generated are unpredictable(in my scenario)

Comment: Why do you want to alias the table name?  There must be a better a approach.

Comment: Because I'm gonna append a huge joins query(they also have patient_problem resulting in `unique table/alias` error ) to the above one.

Comment: I do not see any joins.  Is it a one-to-many?  Why is there id=71 in the generated query?  Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: My apologies id=71 is a typo. I've edited what I am trying to do

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what the variable `joins` is or how it was constructed.  To alias tables in a join build your query like

Rails 3

```
PatientProblem.joins("as p1 OUTER JOIN patient_problem as p2 on ...")
```

or

```
PatientProblem.find(:all, :joins => "as p1 OUTER JOIN patient_problem as p2 ON ...")
```

Comment: This just gives me ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"

Comment: @WylliamJudd, for Rails 4 syntax check http://stackoverflow.com/a/19700056/643500

Comment: I've found: "OUTER JOIN pateint_problem p1 on p1.item_id = items.id"

Answer (score 0):

you can make singleton methods for that and write the query one time and use may time like

```
def self.p1
#your active record query here.
end
```

and call like

```
PatientProblem.p1
```

Comment: could do better with `find_by_sql` but this has nothing to do with aliasing  associations

Comment: `PatientProblem.p1` is totally diffrent from `p.patient_problems` and also I'm looking for how to set alias table name for associations in run time

Answer (score -2):

**Update**

You can simply change the table name in your code:

```
Patient.table_name="p2"
```

I'm not sure if this would break anything else though ... so good luck!

**Orignal Answer**

One solution may be to define a separate model for each type of patient_problem and then do something like this:

```
class PatientProblem2 < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.set_table_name "p2"
 ...
end
```

Another solution may be to use the ActiveRecord  query interface which will allows for significant query flexibility:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Perhaps you can be more specific on the nature problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The table name is still `patient_problem` he just wants to alias it

Comment: `p2` is alias name not table name

Comment: This will cause SQL to complain that there is no table named p2.