# How to only use tag_cloud for current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, tag-cloud

In my **application_controller** I have this:

```
  def tag_cloud
    @tags = Tag.top_20.sort{ |x,y| x.id <=> y.id } if current_user
  end
```

which will make the tag count work for all tags from all users, but instead I want the `tag_cloud` to show only the tags of the `current_user`. I tried this:

```
  def tag_cloud
    @tags = current_user.tags.top_20.sort{ |x,y| x.id <=> y.id } if current_user
  end
```

but that gave me an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `top_20' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in `tag_cloud'
```

even though `top_20` is defined in **tag.rb**:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings

    scope :top_20, -> {
      where("taggings_count != 0").order("taggings_count DESC").limit(15)
    }
end
```

I'm using the **[acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)** gem. Thank you!

### UPDATES

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
  acts_as_taggable
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :activities
  has_many :activity_likes
  has_many :liked_activities, through: :activity_likes, class_name: 'Activity', source: :liked_activity
  has_many :liked_comments, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'Comment', source: :liked_comment
  has_many :valuation_likes
  has_many :habit_likes
  has_many :goal_likes
  has_many :quantified_likes
  has_many :comment_likes
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :habits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :levels
  has_many :combine_tags
  has_many :valuations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :quantifieds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :results, through: :quantifieds
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :habits, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantifieds, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
  User.tag_counts_on(:tags)

  def count_mastered
    @res = habits.reduce(0) do |count, habit|
    habit.current_level == 6 ? count + 1 : count
    end
  end

  def count_challenged
    @challenged_count = habits.count - @res
  end

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
        user.email = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join+"@mailinator.com"
        user.save!
      end
    end

  def self.koala(auth)
    access_token = auth['token']
    facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
    facebook.get_object("me?fields=name,picture")
  end


  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Forgets a user. NOT SURE IF I REMOVE
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

   # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  def good_results_count
    results.good_count
  end

  # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

private 

    def from_omniauth? 
      provider && uid 
    end

      # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email 
      self.email = email.downcase unless from_omniauth? 
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

**tags_controller**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'pages#home', as: :tag
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "conceal",           default: false
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "missed_days"
    t.text     "missed_levels"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "image"
  end
```

**goal.rb**

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_many :notifications
    has_many :notes
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
    scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: false) }
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :goal_likes
  has_many :likers, through: :goal_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker

    scope :top_3, -> do
      order("deadline").
      limit(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by what you mean by: "since my tag_cloud uses multiple models". Are you trying to combine the tags from several model instances into a single tag cloud or what? Anyways I think that your custom Tag, Tagger / classes and migrations are messing up ActsAsTaggable and you may be adding the tags to the wrong table from what it expects when creating them.

Comment: Yes I am combining the tags from several model instances into a single tag cloud, which I am showing in the sidebar, which is why `def tag_cloud` is in the `application_controller`. I don't think it's messing up though simply because everything else works about it. The `tag_cloud` looks beautiful. It's just making it only show for the `current_user`. I'm hoping this is just a simple solution we're missing @maxcal

Comment: Since acts-as-taggable-on uses Rails scopes and and collections it is probably trivial to do the same thing with [`.merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) or by just combining collections - without your custom classes. If you look at the [Tagging](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tagging.rb) and [Tag classes](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb) you will realise that its pretty naive to belive that you can just swap them out with a tiny stubs without problems.

Comment: So is there no way to fix this @maxcal ? I'm willing to get ugly with it as long as it gets the job done. I rather avoid rewriting all my code since it was a long, hard path to get here.

Comment: See my edit. Removing the two classes is probably a lot less work than you imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `acts-as-taggable-on` does not actually use your Tag class. Or to be more specific - it works when you do `Tags.top_20` since you are calling it on your tag class. But the `User#tags` relationship actually uses `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` which explains the `NoMethodError`.

ActsAsTaggableOn seems to [have this functionality built in](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-most-or-least-used-tags) already though:

```
current_user.tags.most_used(20)
```

### Addition:

> I am combining the tags from several model instances into a single tag
>   cloud, which I am showing in the sidebar.

There is nothing in this requirement which says that you need to create a `Tag` or `Tagging` class. In fact doing so is likely to cause you and other developers a bunch of grief. The fact that the tag cloud on your home page works does not change the fact that you most likely are creating a bunch of future issues by replacing two relatively complex components ([Tagging](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tagging.rb) and [Tag classes](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb)) with tiny stubs willy-nilly.

If you look at the [`tag_cloud` implementation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tags_helper.rb) is pretty easy to see that it takes a ActiveRecord::Relation or a collection or just any old enumerable such as an array.

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  module TagsHelper
    # See the wiki for an example using tag_cloud.
    def tag_cloud(tags, classes)
      return [] if tags.empty?

      max_count = tags.sort_by(&:taggings_count).last.taggings_count.to_f

      tags.each do |tag|
        index = ((tag.taggings_count / max_count) * (classes.size - 1))
        yield tag, classes[index.nan? ? 0 : index.round]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Since collections are just fancy pants versions of arrays merging them together is as easy as:

```
@tags = foo.tags + bar.tags
```

However joining relations together is a bit more complex since Rails currently does not support the SQL OR clause. (Its coming in Rails 5). You would either have to load and merge the collections as above or [create your own where clause with AREL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and) if multiple SQL queries is a performance issue.

Comment: I'm a bit to lazy to setup ActsAsTaggableOn to verify but you can easily test this by `current_user.tags.first.class.name`

Comment: `current_user.tags.most_used(10)` shows nothing in the tag_cloud and `current_user.tags.first.class.name` gives the error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'sort_by' for "NilClass":String):` for the `tag_cloud`

Comment: Maybe I need to add something to the model @maxcal to make it work with my code? Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: I guess I should have added that you should test `current_user.tags.first.class.name` with [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md) or `abort`.  But the result is still useful. The fact that you got "NilClass" and not "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag" tells me that the current_user does not seem to have any tags. You can debug it by `current_user.tags.size`.

Comment: This gives `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `empty?' for 0:Fixnum):` Maxcal, which is weird because the user does have tags. I show those tags in the show pages like this `<%= raw @model_name.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t), class: 'label label-primary' } %> `

Comment: And I submit them like this `f.text_field :tag_list`

Comment: I also have a tagging model `class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end` maybe that will help shed some light :-]

Comment: Can you add your `User` model to the question? I'm starting to believe you may be setting up the relation or ActsAsTaggableOn in some strange way.

Comment: That sound like it may be the culprit as well. Maybe you should try rolling back and just installing ActsAsTaggableOn as detailed in the readme. Get rid of your Taggable and Tag class.

Comment: I can't though because I need them since my tag_cloud uses multiple models and that was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the models and what you mean by "since my tag_cloud uses multiple models"?

Comment: Here's a rough gist of it: https://github.com/bvvnbsp/tags. I'll update the question as we speak

Comment: I added everything @maxcal that I thought you might find helpful. The models are habits, goals, valuations, and quantifieds. Each of those has tagging. I added goals above because the others may get redundant. Please let me know if you need further code or explanation :-]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80949/discussion-between-anthonygalli-com-and-maxcal).

Comment: Hey @maxcal made a few comments in discussion. Please don't give up on me yet!