# Rails: Displaying published items and unpublished items of current user as ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I wanted to know is it possible to do the following 2 things at once:

- View all items with status `published`.
- View items for current user with any status.

I have this code:

```
# Item model
scope :published, -> { where(status: 'published') }
scope :unpublished, -> { where.not(status: 'published') }
scope :by_user, -> (user_id) { where(user: user_id) }

# Item controller
def index
 @items = Item.published + Item.unpublished.by_user(current_user.id)
end
```

The problem is that `@items` are an `Array`, but I want `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

If you want to know why I need this, it's a simple answer:

```
@items.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer to informs others when your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in [Rails: How to chain scope queries with OR instead of AND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and) I think you have at least four options:

1) Write a scope that combines your existing ones, something like:

```
scope :published_or_unpublished_by_user, -> (user_id) { where('status = ? OR (status != ? and user = ?)', 'published', 'published', user_id) }
```

2) Use a gem like [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel).

3) Use [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

4) Wait for the `.or` syntax coming in Rails 5.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4.x doesn't support `OR` or `UNION` queries yet, therefore I would suggest a new scope that combines the other scopes with subqueries (the database should be able to optimize them):

```
# in the model
scope :visible_for_user, ->(user) {
  where(
    'items.id IN (?) OR items.id IN (?)',
    Item.published, Item.unpublished.by_user(user.id)
  )
}

# in the controller
@items = Item.visible_for_user(current_user)
```

Please note that the above is a general solution when you want to union existing scope. In this specific example you might get a better performance with a optimized scope:

```
scope :visible_for_user, ->(user) { 
  where("items.status = 'published' OR items.user_id = ?", user.id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

I see, you are trying to find unpublished items from current user. You can do it in my scope.

```
scope :current_user_not_published, ->(user_id) 
      {where('status != ? AND user = ?', 'published', user_id)}
```

**Controller:**

```
# Item controller
def index
 @published_items = Item.published
 @current_user_unpublished_utems = Item.current_user_not_published(current_user.id)
end
```

OR

```
#in this case it will be @items[0] published, @items[1] c.not_published

def index
  @items = [Item.published, Item.current_user_not_published(current_user.id)]
end
```

Comment: `@items` is an `Array`, so I can't do `@items.find(params[:id])`

Comment: after `@items = Item.published` becomes array of objects, u are not able to use activerecord method to find it. also thats index page, how u getting `params[:id]`, r u searching it ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can. But this is not what I would get. See other answers. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, i see. probably i misunderstand the question. glad u fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. If your published is a boolean column inside the items table, then published/unpublished is determined by your published being true or false.

Then in your items_controller.rb you can so this.

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item_published = @item.where(published: true)
  @item_unpublished = @item.where(published: false)
end
```

So now in your item show page you can do this

```
<h2>Your Published Items</h2>

<% @item_published.each do |item| %>
  <li><%= item.name %></li>
  ...
<% end %>

<hr>

<h2>Your Unpublished Items</h2>

<% @item_unpublished.each do |item| %>
  <li><%= item.name %></li>
  ...
<% end %>
```