# One query for multiple boolean conditions limit 1 per condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to clean up some queries on an app I work on. Right now I'm performing 4 queries to the same table for very similar information

```
MyModel.order("for_date ASC").where('boolean_column_1 = ?', 'Y').last
MyModel.order("for_date ASC").where('boolean_column_2 = ?', 'Y').last
MyModel.order("for_date ASC").where('boolean_column_3 = ?', 'Y').last
MyModel.order("for_date ASC").where('boolean_column_4 = ?', 'Y').last
```

My question is: what's the best way to clean this up? I'd like to keep it to only 4 values returned, because it's a big table. I can't think of a good way to reduce this to one query 

ruby version 2.1, rails version 3.2

Comment: Are you really using Rails version 2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and

Comment: ruby version 2.1, rails 3.2

Comment: The issue is it needs to limit one record returned for each boolean condition met.  something along the lines of `MyModel.where("b1 = ? OR b2 = ?", Y, Y).limit_one_per_OR`