# OR-ing multiple named scopes in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, named-scope

I have a Car model like this.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :modern, -> do
        where(make_date: 2018)
    end
    scope :black, -> do
        where(color: :black)
    end
    scope :bmw, -> do
        where(make: :bmw)
    end
end
```

I can find all modern cars by `Car.modern`.

I can find all black cars by `Car.black`.

I can find all BMW cars by `Car.bmw`.

How do I use these named scopes to find all cars that are either 'black' or 'modern' ? So that i can have Old-Black-Nissan, Modern-White-BMW, Moder-black-Ford all in a single resultset.

Using Rails 4.2.8

Comment: The answer is different depending on which version of rails you are using (>=5 or <5).

Comment: using Rails 4.2.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: How to chain scope queries with OR instead of AND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and)

Comment: If you could upgrade to rails 5, this version has added support for OR in ActiveRecord. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or) gem. More info [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/rails-how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and). Please search thoroughly before asking questions yourself. Most likely someone stumbled upon that problem before.