# Ruby - IF or OR condition on a JOINS statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I specify a `OR` condition on a `joins` statement? Basically I don't want the `joins` for `where(:tenant_id => User.current_tenant`. If I try `OR` condition I get the following error.

I get the following error.

Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins] [catalog/explorer]

```
  scope :public_service_templates,                  ->         { joins(:miq_user_roles).where(miq_user_roles: { settings: nil}).or(where(:tenant_id => User.current_tenant)) }
```

Comment: Could you write down the pure SQL query you want AR to generate? 
It's a good way to see basically if it's possible in SQL first of all.

Comment: That is your model name for `tenant_id ` column?

Comment: No `Users` is part of a different model. The scope is on `service_templates` model. `service_templates` has access to `Users` model. If I remove the `OR` and just use `where` condition then the filter works but I want it to be a `OR` condition.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 6, you can do the following:

```
scope :first_query, -> { joins(:miq_user_roles).where(miq_user_roles: { settings: nil }) }

scope :second_query, -> { where(:tenant_id => User.current_tenant)) }

scope :first_query_or_second_query, -> { first_query.or(self.second_query) }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there no way to add OR condition directly on the first query?

Comment: Didn't try it before tbh, but this one could be a good reference and you can try the multiple solutions there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684311/how-to-chain-scope-queries-with-or-instead-of-and) @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

The title says "IF" or "OR" so I am a bit unclear if you are looking for both templates where `"miq_user_roles"."setttings" IS NULL OR "service_template"."tenant_id" = SOME_ID` or if you are looking for `"miq_user_roles"."setttings" IS NULL` but if that is empty then return `"service_template"."tenant_id" = SOME_ID`.

*Assumptions*

1. You are looking for the former combined OR condition
2. The reasoning is that `where(:tenant_id => User.current_tenant)` may not have a relationship with `MiqUserRole` and thus the `join` prohibits the return of the appropriate values.

If so just use `left_joins` instead of `joins`.

This will create an outer join and will make this part (`miq_user_roles: { settings: nil}`) of the condition non impactful on this part `where(:tenant_id => User.current_tenant)`); however you will still have to add the `left_joins` to the second condition for structural compatibility.
e.g.

```
scope :public_service_templates,-> { 
  left_joins(:miq_user_roles)
   .where(miq_user_roles: { settings: nil})
   .or(left_joins(:miq_user_roles)
       .where(:tenant_id => User.current_tenant))
}
```

Alternatively you  could use `Arel` for the condition which will allow the OR to be part of the single where clause (without needing to merge scopes) e.g.

```
scope :public_service_templates,-> {
  left_joins(:miq_user_roles)
    .where(
       MiqUserRole.arel_table[:settings].eq(nil).or(
         arel_table[:tenant_id].eq(User.current_tenant.id)
       )
    )
}
```

Additionally not sure what `User.current_tenant` returns. Depending on implementation you need to pass an instance of `User` to this call e.g.

```
scope :public_service_templates,->(user) {#...
```

then you would call as `ServiceTemplate.public_service_templates(user)`