# ActiveRecord - Retrieve one record for each association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

`Merchant has_many Shops`

`Shop belongs_to Merchant`

i.e. One `merchant` (Starbucks) can have many shops locations.

I'm using Gecoder to get the nearby shops, e.g. `@shops = Shop.near("Times Square")`.

**I would like to return only 1 record for each merchant only. I.e. `@shops` only contain 1 Starbucks, 1 Subway, but is a collection.**

Sorry I've been Googling and searching on SO to no avail. Perhaps I'm not using the right word to describe what I want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled a bit more and stumbled on `group by` for SQL.

If I have `4 shops belonging to 2 merchants` near a location called "Raffles Place", within `1 kilometer`.

Calling `Shop.near("Raffles Place",1)` returns `4 shops`.

If I add a `group` to `Shop.near("Raffles Place",1).group(:merchant_id)`, only `2 shops` are returned.

This can be used with other conditions too, such as `Shop.where(:featured=>true).group(:merchant_id)` to only show 1 shop per featured merchant.

Answer (score 1):

To answer what you should be googling for, joined or combined queries within a `scope` will probably solve what you are looking to do.  If you build a scope with `:or` logic combining queries, one each for each shop, limited to the first record, you should get what you are looking for.

I won't pretend that I understand Geocoder or advanced scopes enough to do this, but I found an example that shows this approach in another problem:

```
named_scope :or, lambda { |l, r| {
  :conditions => 
      "annotations.id IN (#{l.send(:construct_finder_sql,{:select => :id})}) or " + 
      "annotations.id IN (#{r.send(:construct_finder_sql,{:select => :id})})" 
}}
```

This comes from this SO question:  [Combine two named scopes with OR (instead of AND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482940/combine-two-named-scopes-with-or-instead-of-and)

Hope this helps you find the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Wow 2 simple lines of code, but my pea brain's not really getting it. I'll give it a try.  You can assume that I just want a Shop.all by where each unique `:merchant_id` is only represented once.

Comment: To be clear, this is not code that fixes your exact problem.  It is only an example of a concept that you might start googling for to learn how to solve your problem.

Comment: Yup of course =). I was just hoping that Rails might have some magic bullets to solve the problem. I get it that it's a query with a "sub-query".

Comment: Sorry if I confused you, the `group` statement is just what I needed.