# Using OR with queries in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Rails3 I have:

```
Class Teacher
  #  active                 :boolean
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects

Class Subject
  #  active                 :boolean
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
```

I am trying to construct a Teacher scope that returns all `Teachers` that are `active` or are associated with a `Subject` that is `active`.

These scopes work individually, but how to combine them as a *single* scope with an OR?

```
scope :active_teachers, where(active: true)
scope :more_active_teachers, joins(:subjects).where(:subjects => {active: true})
```

I've tried this without success:

```
scope :active_teachers, where(active: true).or(joins(:subjects)
      .where(:subjects => {active: true}))
```

**UPDATE:**

I thought I had a solution, but this no longer lazy loads, hits the database twice and — most importantly — returns an array rather than an AR object!

```
scope :active_teachers, where(active: true) |
                        joins(:subjects).where(:subjects => {active: true})
```

Comment: See my answer to the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40269481/1876622).  Also note similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445203/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482940/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `Squeel` to your rescue. More details [here](https://github.com/ernie/squeel#predicates).

Using that, you could define something like:

```
class Teacher
  ...
  scope :active_teachers, joins{subjects}.where {(active == true) | (subjects.active == true)}
  ...
end
```

Comment: +1 for Squeel. It's an excellent resource for complicated apps.

Comment: +1. Thanks Puneet. I was hoping to avoid another gem, but Squeel seems like the ideal solution and I will no doubt need it later in the project anyway. You get the big tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the short answer is you can't.

Oring in the code is going to break lazy loading ... really no way around it as you need the database to make the evaluation. ActiveRecord can't make the evaluations on the scopes without executing each subclause individually.

Something like this the following should work:

```
joins(:subjects).where("subjects.active = true OR teachers.active = true")
```

Not quite as elegant, but can be wrapped into a method for reuse.

Comment: You would also need joins:
`scope :active_teachers, joins(:subjects).where("subjects.active = true OR teachers.active = true")`

Comment: Even if this isn't as elegant, it's a lot more straightforward.  At some point, it's not worth jumping through hoops just to or two conditions together.

Comment: That's how I feel about it

Comment: Thanks Toby - I agree with your sentiments. Unfortunately I can't get the above query to give the result I'm after (ie. seems to double count the teachers with active subjects and return no teachers who are themselves active). I'd rather avoid another gem, but I think I'll need to go with Squeel. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by dropping to AREL. See this SO Question for how to do that.

[AREL OR Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition)

Or from the [AREL Source Code README.md](https://github.com/rails/arel). I think (but haven't verified) that this would translate to the following for your particular example.

```
teachers.where(teachers[:active].eq(true).or(subjects[:active].eq(true)))
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Dave! I'll need to further explore that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rails pull request for this (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9052), but in the meantime, some one has created a monkey patch that you can include in your initializers that will allow you to do this and still give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/250eaaceef234dd8971b

With that, you'll be able to OR your scopes like this

```
Teacher.active_teachers.or.more_active_teachers
```

or write a new scope

```
scope :combined_scopes, active_teachers.or.more_active_teachers
```

Comment: Thanks keithepley, I'll keep my eye on that one. I'm a bit reluctant to step off the canonical path, but that patch would do the trick. Thanks.