# Combining multiple named scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, named-scope

I am trying to combine two scopes or add some more to an existing scope.

```
scope :public_bids, -> {
  where(status: [Status::ACCEPTED, Status::OUTBID, Status::SOLD, Status::NO_SALE],
        bid_type: [BidType::MANUAL, BidType::AUTO, BidType::LIVE])
scope :outbid_maxbids, -> {
  where(status: Status::OUTBID, bid_type: BidType::MAXBID)
```

I am having trouble determining how to `OR` them together or combine then into one scope. Any suggestions/guidance? I would prefer that they be combined into one single scope.

Comment: See my answer to the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40269481/1876622).  Also note similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482940/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381619/)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried using `or` in a scope, but you may be able to chain the scopes together using Rails 5's new `or` method, like this:

```
scope :public_or_outbid, -> {
  where(status: [Status::ACCEPTED, Status::OUTBID, Status::SOLD, Status::NO_SALE], bid_type: [BidType::MANUAL, BidType::AUTO, BidType::LIVE])\
  .or(where(status: Status::OUTBID, bid_type: BidType::MAXBID))
}
```

(Note that this only works in Rails 5)

You certainly can chain the conditions together like this:

```
MyObj.public_bids.or(MyObj.outbid_maxbids)
```

See this answer for more detail: [Rails 5: ActiveRecord OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753168/rails-5-activerecord-or-query)

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't upgraded to 5 yet :(

Comment: Well what's the holdup? It's almost out of beta! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 and older do not support `OR` query "natively". Looks like it will be introduced in Rails 5.

For now, you would have to use SQL with `.where` method:

```
YourModel.where('field1 = ? OR field2 = ?', 1, 2)
```

But, in your case, you are selecting using `IN` and `=` queries and the first field is in both scopes. So, it would not make much sense. Anyway, if you really have to, you might get away [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865634/52317):

```
data = YourModel.public_bids.outbid_maxbids
YourModel.where(data.where_values.inject(:or))
```