# ActiveRecord: How to do an 'OR' merge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to decouple ActiveRecord queries in a model so they are reusable in different circumstances. To keep it simple, say I have a model called Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.over_stocked
    where('stock_count >= ?', 20)
  end

  def self.expensive
    where('price >= ?', 100.0)
  end
end
```

If I wanted to create a new method to find products that have too much stock AND are expensive, I could merge the two queries:

```
...
def self.costly_stock
  # SQL => '... WHERE stock_count >= 20 AND price >= 100.0'
  over_stocked.merge(expensive)
end
```

However how can I use these two methods to create a new query for products that are either expensive OR are over stocked?
E.g:

```
...
def expensive_or_over_stocked
  # SQL => '... WHERE stock_count >= 20 OR price >= 100.0'
  ...
end
```

Basically I'm looking for something like `merge` that uses OR rather than AND. Ideally the solution would return an ActiveRecord Relation and not an Array. Obviously I could rewrite the query with  `where('stock_count >= ? OR price >= ?', 20, 100.0)` however that wouldn't be very DRY

Comment: I don't think there's an easy answer to this one. I'd love someone to prove me wrong though.

Comment: @Pete - see this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query

Comment: @Master_Yoda thanks, I saw that question, though unfortunately it doesn't address my goal of having reusable and decoupled queries that can be merged either with an AND or OR. I also do don't think dropping down into Arel is an elegant solution

Comment: I agree, but note that the most liked answer in the community in a really popular question is your non-DRY approach. It seems like AR doesn't really support what you want here.

Comment: You could try this [plugin](https://github.com/woahdae/active_record_or). Came across it in the linked answer, havent tried it

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482940/combine-two-named-scopes-with-or-instead-of-and

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution. One can argue how DRY it is.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :over_stocked, -> { where.not(stock_count: [0..19]) }
  scope :expensive, -> { where.not(price: [0..99]) }
  scope :costly_stock, -> { expensive.over_stocked }
  scope :neither_expensive_nor_over_stocked, -> { where(stock_count: [0..19]).where(price: [0..99]) }

  def self.expensive_or_over_stocked
    Product.where.not(id: Product.neither_expensive_nor_over_stocked.pluck(:id))
  end
end
```

Comment: If you use`select` instead of `pluck` it should do one query, by way of a sub-query, instead of two.